# IE 8 PNG body background problem

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, png, background

I've got a problem with IE 8 CSS.

```
*  {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0; }


 img, fieldset  { border:none; }

 body  {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
```

In the page:

```
<body style="background:#FFFFFF url(../public/img/s5_fa_bot_bg.png) no-repeat bottom center">
```

The png image is displaying correctly in Firefox and Safari but on top in IE8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually an HTML problem, an unclosed div caused the png to show on top of the page.

Thanks for your time and effort.

Answer (score 1):

This is an IE8 bug, your png background image needs to be at least 4x4px.

More info @ http://stevelove.org/2009/07/10/png-background-repeat-bug-in-internet-explorer-7-and-8/

Answer (score 0):

Your shorthand is wrong, it should be:

```
background:#FFFFFF url(../public/img/s5_fa_bot_bg.png) no-repeat center bottom;
```

Notice that I have switched the horizontal and the vertical position at the end.

Comment: Do you have an example online?

Comment: Here is an example online:
http://communication.pcsnet.it/PCSNetFE/Corsi/DefaultCorsiFE.aspx